# Javascript Event stopPropagation on different Event Types

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, propagation

I have a  tag, and when 'focused' I display a .  When I click on the document body I would like this  to close.  However, this doesn't seem to work when using two different event types:

```
<input id='input' />  
<div id='div style='display:none;'>
</div>

$('#input').focus( function(e){  
   e.stopPropagation();  
   $('#div').show()  
});

$(document).click( function(){  
   $('#div').hide();  
});
```

It appears that the `e.stopPropagation()` only stop propagation of the 'onfocus' event.  Since when I switch the code to be:  `$('#input').click()`, then it works fine.

Just curious if there is anyway to make this work with the above code?  (would like to know JS a bit better)

Thanks!

Comment: Was it a typo in your question that you are missing the end ' from your div id?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this

```
$('#input').bind('focus blur', function() {
    $('#div').toggle();
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/u9xwb/

Comment: Yes, I could do that.  But is there a way to do it with the way I am trying?  This would provide me with a deeper understanding of javascript and provide guidance of certain areas of the language to study.

Comment: This is not the answer on the given question

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it only kills the event you are subscribed to, you need to stop the click event as well on the input.

```
$('#input').focus( function(e){  
   e.stopPropagation();  
   $('#div').show();
}).click( function(e){  
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click( function(){  
   $('#div').hide();  
});
```

Comment: yes.  This will work.  I was kind of wondering if I could tie into the 'click event' from the 'focus event' somehow for the same element.  But not sure if you can.

Comment: it will only stop the current event